# datatables export pdf with utf-8 support

Tags: datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to export table as excel, pdf.
Every thing works fine except this:
Export pdf and the table contains non English characters (like Arabic). In this case the pdf show strange characters.
So how could I fix Arabic characters problem in pdf export?

[image: datatables pdf with arabic contents]

Comment: Anyone get the solution of this question.. Please tell me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555869/5316882 has a better answer. Didn't flag this as duplicate as that question is newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [pdfmake documentation](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side) on the topic of custom fonts. My guess (hard to say without being able to see the page) is that the default pdfmake font doesn't include those characters.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add our fonts in vfs_fonts.js and refer to those fonts in JS file.

- create a new vfs_fonts.js file containing your font files
- assign pdfMake.fonts in your javascript
- specify the font in your doc-definition

Refer: https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/